# How to compute CRC checksum in R compatible with output with Linux `cksum` command

Tags: r, crc, digest

I am downloading files from a site that provides checksums (as decimals) computed with the Linux `cksum` command.

In R I can do a CRC-32 checksum in decimal format with:

```
library(digest)
strtoi(digest(file_path, algo="crc32", file=TRUE), base=16L)
```

Is there a similar command I can use to get a checksum for a file that is compatible with the Linux `cksum` command? I need a cross-platform approach that preferably does not require software external to R. The [wikipedia page on cksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cksum) states that:

"The standard cksum command, as found on most UNIX-like OS (including GNU/Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X, and Solaris) uses a CRC algorithm based on the ethernet standard frame check and is therefore interoperable between implementations. It is not however compatible with the CRC-32 calculation."

I have also found `cksum` in the `bitops` package, but I am unclear how best to compute a checksum for a file using that function.

Comment: Source code is http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cksum.c if you want to inspect the algorithm. Or wrap that code in Rcpp...

Comment: Or send us a patch / pull request for the digest package.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk. This is looking like a good option for a fast CRC compatible with linux's cksum. Assume you could accept a modified version of the GPL-3 code linked to by Spacedman?

Comment: The digest package is GPL-2 licensed. I am not a license lawyer, but as you asked, I believe this means that I cannot mix. Dunno.

Answer (score 2):

Get the file size, read into a raw vector, convert to char, use bitops' cksum:

```
cksumfile = function(f){
   size = file.info(f)$size
   c = file(f,"rb")
   csum = cksum(rawToChar(readBin(c,raw(),n=size)))
   close(c)
   csum
}
```

test:

```
> cksumfile("/etc/passwd")
[1] 1594741334
> system("cksum /etc/passwd")
1594741334 1953 /etc/passwd
```

This edited version opens and closes the connection explicitly to stop a warning.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for arbitrary binary files. For example,  `cksumfile("/bin/bash")`, returns `Error in rawToChar(readBin(c, raw(), n = size)) :  embedded nul in string`

Comment: Ugh. Yeah, character can't store zeroes and cksum uses character therefore cksum can only work on stuff that doesn't have zeroes. Suggest hacking bitops' C code to read raw vectors. Sorry!